# Evil-mode mixed tabs & spaces indentation

Tags: evil, indentation

I'm having extreme issues at the moment with evil mode where I am working on Jade/Pug and Stylus files for Node.JS where it is white space sensitive. I installed  [pug-mode](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-pug-mode) but when you indent via >> the indentation goes 4 spaces and on the 2nd >> the spaces get converted into one tab I think. Backspace isn't even removing the tabwidth of spaces, only the tabs. Also, how do I setup proper indentation with evil-mode for files that are not known to emacs like .styl (stylus) files? I am still new to emacs where I am experiencing hell with this mixed white-space of tabs and spaces along with the non-intuitive indentation.

What I want:

- tab and >> does the same indentation
- backspace removes a tabwidth of indentation
- autoindent when in insert state and carriage returned as well with 'o'
- no mixed tabs or spaces
- stylus files having proper indentation with CSS coloring

[image: what it looks like in white-space mode]

Comment: Honestly, the best way of going at it is creating a proper major mode that sets up the right indentation for you. That's how Evil delegates most of the indentation business, with the notable exception of `>`.

Comment: How do I go about that? Don't I have to do something for both emacs and evil as well?

Comment: What I mean is, don't I have to create my own mode and modify many variables or functions for both emacs and evil? Do I not use other premade modes? How do I even go about finding what needs to be created or changed? Apropos search for the "indentation" keyword? Read the source code of .el files? What documentation should I use?

Comment: This is at least two separate questions: 1. How to make pug-mode and `>>` play together, 2. What to do about files without major modes for them, 3. Your other questions about how to learn how to make major modes